# Dot Product doesn't behave like normal function

Tags: functions, built-in-symbols, dot

I am trying to slightly modify the `Dot` function by treating it like a usual function, but soon I notice something weird about it.

Suppose there is a set `set = {λ}`, and I want to force `Dot[a, λ]` (having **two** arguments) to just print out `{a, λ}`.

```
set = {λ};

Unprotect[Dot];
Clear[Dot]
Dot[x_, λ_] := Module[{}, Print[{x, λ}]] /; MemberQ[set, λ]
Unprotect[Dot];

(* test *)
Dot[a, λ]
Dot[a, b, λ]
```

The two tests print out

```
{a,λ}
```

and

```
{b, λ}
{a.b, λ}
```

respectively.

However, the same code for a different function `Dott` behave completly differently,

```
set = {λ};
Dott[x_, λ_] := 
 Module[{}, Print[{x, λ}]] /; MemberQ[set, λ]

(* tests *)
Dott[a, λ]
Dott[a, a, λ]
```

where the two tests print out `{a,λ}` and an unevaluated expression `Dott[a, a, λ]` respectively, and as expected.

I wonder **what is going on under the hood (it appears that `Dot` is trying to exhaust all possible "two-factor product" given any number of dotted factors), and how to properly temper with the `Dot` product?** (my ultimate goal is to adapt it for some non-commutative algebra).

Comment: Not wanting to mess with `Dot` at the moment, consider that `Clear` does not clear attributes (`Attributes@Dot`).  (I'm not sure that leads to the answer, btw.)

Comment: "my ultimate goal is to adapt it for some non-commutative algebra" - then you should be using `Inner[]` instead of messing around with built-in functions.

Comment: It has something to do with pattern-matching. Try `Dot[x, y, c] /. Dot[a_, b_] /; MemberQ[{c}, b] :> {a, b}` and then `Trace` it to see what pattern matches are tried.

Comment: @J.M. the `Dot` I want to define is not the geometric dot/inner product between vectors. It's more like abstract matrix multiplication, where some products are commutative while some are not.

Comment: `Inner[]` is usable for matrices: `Inner[NonCommutativeMultiply, {{a11, a12}, {a21, a22}}, {{b11, b12}, {b21, b22}}, Plus]`.

Comment: @J.M. I agree, but unfortunately, I don't have actual matrixes. I only have abstract elements like `a, b, c, d, λ, μ, ...`, where the product between some of them is commutative, while that of some others is non-commutative with other funny properties. I want to formulate this kind of structure.

Comment: In that case, I think `NonCommutativeMultiply[]` would be safer to modify than `Dot[]`. `Dot[]` is sufficiently low-level that I won't be surprised if anything breaks right after you modify its definition. Alternatively, you could use something that doesn't have a built-in meaning like `CenterDot[]`.

Comment: @J.M. Indeed at this point maybe it's easier to simply define the product from scratch. `CenterDot[]` looks nice. Thanks!